# Twig name for field of view

Tags: views, theming, 8

I have an view that uses the *Unformatted list* format and *Show: fields*.

[image]

I've added the fields to it and the view has _Content type: my_content_type_ filter.

I want to write a template file for the fields in that view, with the following code.

```
{% if field_name == 'field_photo' %}
    ...
{% elseif field_name == 'field_something_else' %}
<div class="something">
    {% for item in items %}
        {{ item.content }}
    {% endfor %}
</div><!-- .something -->
```

I don't know which name to use for the template file.

I've tried the following names, but they don't work. MY_CUSTOM_TYPE stays for the content type I have set in filter for that view.

- field--MY_CUSTOM_TYPE.html.twig
- field--node--MY_CUSTOM_TYPE.html.twig

What is the correct filename for the template file I am trying to use?

Comment: Did you enable twig debugging and look at the suggestions?

Comment: @Kevin yes, and there are no suggestions for it (on such deep level) - they exists only for the whole view and not for the separate fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use:

**views-view-fields--[view-name]--[[machine-name]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JDJ1q.jpg).html.twig**

Use the machine name if you only want to affect a specific view Display. (IE: when you click + Add button, that other view/display does not get affected). If you wan't all displays to be affected, then don't include the machine name.

**views-view-fields--[view-name].html.twig**

```
{% if fields.field_photo.content|striptags == 'some value' %}
    ...
{% elseif fields.field_something_else.content|striptags == 'some value' %}
<div class="something-specific">
        {{ fields.field_something_else.content }}
</div><!-- .something-specific -->
{% endif %}
```

If you just want to add a div class regardless of the value of the field and not depending on some condition, then simply

`<div class="something">{{ fields.field_machine_name.content }}</div>`

OR you can do this through the Views UI:

[image]

Now, if you need something more global, IE: You want to affect **all Views** that contain your field **and future views** that will contain your field, then you need to use:

**views-view-field--[field-name].html.twig**

```
<div class="something">{{ output -}}</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a detailed answer in this Q: [Overriding views-view-field.html.twig for specific fields](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/200802/specific-field-tag-based-naming-conventions-overriding-views-view-field-html-tw). I'm not quite sure what the options for a content type are, but this is the answer for a template per fieldname: you can use `views-view-field--fieldname.html.twig`.

Of course, don't forget to clear your cache after creating the new template.