# Adding Theme Suggestions Programmatically For Views (Rows & Fields)

Tags: views, 8, theming

For a site I'm currently building I've got a variety of views, all with multiple display modes for different pages.

For example, I have a `venues` view, one block is named `listing` which lists all of my `venues` content type. I have another block which has some more specific contextual filters.

My issue is, this different block is styled the same, and has the same markup as my `listing` block so I don't want to have to duplicate my Twig templates for the rows and fields, for each display mode I have.

What my idea was is to add a function to my `.theme` file that would allow me to list display modes for a certain view, and add a single theme suggestion off that back of that. This way I can rename my Twig templates, and re-use the same ones for row and field level, on as many display modes as I'd like.

As I'm not using a theme suggestions alter hook, I'm not sure how I actually add theme suggestions.

**Here's what I've got so far:**

```
/**
 * Theme suggestions for views.
*/
function spve_preprocess_views_view(&$variables) {
  $view = $variables['view'];
  $id = $view->storage->id();

  // Venues
  if($id === 'venues') {
    // Venues grid
    switch($view->current_display) {
      case 'single_occasion_type_listing':
        $suggestion = 'views-view--venues-grid';
        break;

      default:
        $suggestion = null;
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

Obviously I'd need to replace either `$suggestion` with the correct function to add a theme suggestion, or add a bit at the end of my function to add a theme suggestion based of my `$suggestion` variable.

Answer (score 16):

Had a similar question, and though answers were good, they didn't provide everything for my case. Plus it's been a minute, adding my 3 cents to help expansion...

Add views template suggestions:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_theme_suggestions_HOOK_alter().
 *
 * Add views template suggestions.
 * 
 * @inheritdoc
 */
function HOOK_theme_suggestions_views_view_alter(array &$suggestions, array $variables) {
  return [
    'views_view__' . $variables['view']->id()
  ];
}
```

---

Add views display template suggestions???:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_theme_suggestions_HOOK().
 *
 * Add views template suggestions.
 * 
 * @inheritdoc
 */
function HOOK_theme_suggestions_views_view(array $variables) {
  return [
    'views_view_display__' . $variables['view']->current_display,
  ];
}
```

---

Add views unformatted template suggestions:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_theme_suggestions_HOOK_alter().
 *
 * Add views unformatted template suggestions.
 * 
 * @inheritdoc
 */
function HOOK_theme_suggestions_views_view_unformatted_alter(array &$suggestions, array $variables) {
  return [
    'views_view_unformatted__' . $variables['view']->id()
  ];
}
```

---

Add views field template suggestions:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_theme_suggestions_HOOK().
 *
 * Add views field template suggestions.
 * 
 * @inheritdoc
 */
function HOOK_theme_suggestions_views_view_field(array $variables) {
  return [
    'views_view_field__' . $variables['field']->field
  ];
}
```

---

And I also want to add that if you're working in a custom module you may need to add the template files to your theme registry using `hook_theme()`:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_theme().
 *
 * Add template files to the theme.
 * 
 * @inheritdoc
 */
function HOOK_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
  return [
    // Field templates.
    'views_view_field__my_field_name' => [
      'template' => 'views-view-field--my-field-name',
      'base hook' => 'views_view_field',
    ],
    // Views templates.
    'views_view__my_views_block' => [
      'template' => 'views-view--my-views-id',
      'base hook' => 'views_view',
    ],
    // Views unformatted templates.
    'views_view_unformatted__my_views_block' => [
      'template' => 'views-view-unformatted--my-views-id',
      'base hook' => 'views_view_unformatted',
    ],
  ];
}
```

And the above `HOOK_theme()` would correspond to the following Twig template files:

1. `views-view-field--my-field-name.html.twig`
2. `views-view--my-views-id.html.twig`
3. `views-view-unformatted--my-views-id.html.twig`

Comment: Thanks for this!! Searched for half a day!

Comment: Great answer with all the possible scenarios! Thank you @Prestosaurus!

Answer (score 11):

Your Solution is good, but there is a cleaner one. You can use the `hook_theme_suggestions_HOOK_alter`, so you do not have to check if it's a `view` or whatever you want to check.

In your case it would look like this:

```
    function spve_theme_suggestions_views_view_alter(array &$suggestions, array $variables) {
        // If you want you can add a template suggestion for all views
        // based on their ID:
        $suggestions[] = sprintf('views_view__%s', $variables['view']->id());

        // Or you can check the ID, add suggestions, do whatever you want
        // ...
    }

    function spve_theme_suggestions_views_view_field_alter(array &$suggestions, array $variables) {
        // Check here the id, add suggestions, do whatever you want
        // ...
    }
```

More informations in the [Drupal Theme API](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21theme.api.php/function/hook_theme_suggestions_HOOK_alter/8.4.x)

Answer (score 6):

So, eventually I came up with the following solution. Basically I'm checking if the current `$hook` is a view, and then checking if the view is the view I wish to add the suggestions for, and then checks for both row and field levels.

If you find/know a better solution, please share it!

```
function spve_theme_suggestions_alter(array &$suggestions, array $variables, $hook) {

  /**
   * Venues Grid Twig Template Suggestions
   */
  // Firstly check it's a view
  if($hook === 'views_view') {
    // Check if it's the 'venue' view
    if($variables['view']->id() === 'venues') {
      // Check the display mode
      switch($variables['view']->current_display) {
        case 'listing':              
        case 'single_occasion_type_listing':
          $suggestions[] = 'views-view--venues-grid-rows';
          break;
        default:
          break;
      }
    }
  }

  // Firstly check it's a view field
  if($hook === 'views_view_field') {
    // Check if it's the 'venue' view
    if($variables['view']->id() === 'venues') {
      // Check the display mode
      switch($variables['view']->current_display) {
        case 'listing':              
        case 'single_occasion_type_listing':
          $suggestions[] = 'views-view--venues-grid-field';
          break;
        default:
          break;
      }
    }
  }
  /**
   * E/O Venues Grid Twig Template Suggestions
   */
}
```

Answer (score 2):

(Cross-post from [I don't see Views Theme Suggestions](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/249854))

This is a bug in Drupal 8 core, currently being worked on for version <del>8.6</del> 8.7

If you need the functionality now, you have two options:

1. Try the patches from comment #22 (or more recent) on [Issue #2923634](https://www.drupal.org/i/2923634) and the patches on [Issue #2752443](https://www.drupal.org/i/2752443).  Read the comment thread on #2923634 to get a full understanding of what's going on here.
2. Or use the well-vetted patch from comment #139 on [Issue #2118743](https://www.drupal.org/i/2118743) which has been postponed in favor of option 1 above.

I'm using the patch from option 2 ([#2118743](https://www.drupal.org/i/2118743)) successfully. Please note that this does go against the standard core contributor recommendations. But the reason is because #2118743 has a single, well-vetted and working patch for something that is only enabled / used during development, and instead of needing to test out various combinations of two separate patches that are still under development. Once the better solution ([#2923634](https://www.drupal.org/i/2923634) and [#2752443](https://www.drupal.org/i/2752443)) get fixed in core, #2118743 should be obviated and no longer required.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to Daniels answer that suggestions should be formatted with underscores instead of dashes:
`$suggestions[] = 'views_view__venues_grid_rows';`

Answer (score 0):

My problem was a little different, but I think it is relevant here.
I need to provide a theme hook suggestion for an entity that is rendered through the field plugin "Rendered Entity". Here's my solution.

- My module is named "entry"
- My view id is "entries"

In the entry.module file:

```
/**
 * Adds theme suggestions for Field in a View
 *
 * @see hook_theme_suggestions_HOOK_alter()
 * @param array $suggestions
 * @param array $variables
 */
function entry_theme_suggestions_views_view_field_alter(array &$suggestions, array $variables) {
  /** @var \Drupal\views\Entity\View $view */
  $view = $variables['view'];
  if ($view->id() == 'entries') {
    $field = $variables['field'];
    if ($field instanceof \Drupal\views\Plugin\views\field\RenderedEntity) {
      $suggestions[] = 'views_view_field__' . $field->options['view_mode'];
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> This answer is true - [Adding Theme Suggestions Programmatically For Views (Rows & Fields)](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/227709/adding-theme-suggestions-programmatically-for-views-rows-fields#277292)

```
/**
 * Implements hook_theme_suggestions_alter().
 */
function hayly_theme_suggestions_alter(array &$suggestions, array $variables, $hook) {
  $template = '';
  $view_id = $variables['view']->id();
  switch ($hook) {
    case 'views_view':
      $template = 'views_view__' . $view_id;
      break;

    case 'views_view_unformatted':
      $template = 'views_view_unformatted__' . $view_id;
      break;

    case 'views_view_fields':
      $template = 'views_view_fields__' . $view_id;
      break;
  }
  return [$template];
}
```