# Apply page template suggestion to a specific view by a hook?

Tags: views, theming

I have a website running Drupal 8.x with different views. I would like to use a page--template.html.twig template basing to the view ID. Is this possible?

I was thinking of using code similar to the following.

```
function mythemename_theme_suggestions_page_alter(array &$suggestions, array $variables, $hook) {
 if ($hook === 'views_view') {
   if ($variables['view']->id() === 'movies') {
     $suggestions[] = 'page__movies';
   }
 }
}
```

Comment: not sure may be it helps you https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/227709/adding-theme-suggestions-programmatically-for-views-rows-fields

Comment: Tks so much for you help, I did checked that post and so many other before but didn't help me...  luckily 4k4 answer did! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, the code is never run, because you have the hook `page` in the function name and check for the hook `views_view`. Secondly the variables in a page hook don't contain variables from the view, so you have to get them from the route:

```
function mythemename_theme_suggestions_page_alter(array &$suggestions, array $variables) {

  $view_id = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('view_id');
  if ($view_id === 'movies') {
    $suggestions[] = 'page__movies';
  }

}
```

Comment: Amazing! Tks so much!, again, I am just new in this and trying to improve, glad you got to understand what I needed. Xxx :)