# I don't see Views Theme Suggestions

Tags: views, 8

For some reason I don't see the views theme suggestions in my twig debug information? What do I miss?

- In my development.services.yml in set debug to true.
- I do see debug information and theme suggestions from other page items.
- I do see views debug info but not the theme suggestions. See image below:

[image]

On other website I see suggestions like this:

[image]

Comment: This is a duplicate of https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/227709

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is a bug in Drupal 8 core, currently being worked on in several different core issues, many of which have working patches.

If you need the functionality now, you have two options:

1. Try the patches from comment #22 (or more recent) on [Issue #2923634](https://www.drupal.org/i/2923634) and the patches on [Issue #2752443](https://www.drupal.org/i/2752443).  Read the comment thread on #2923634 to get a full understanding of what's going on here.
2. Or use the well-vetted patch from comment #139 on [Issue #2118743](https://www.drupal.org/i/2118743) which has been postponed in favor of option 1 above.

I'm using the patch from option 2 ([#2118743](https://www.drupal.org/i/2118743)) successfully. Please note that this does go against the standard core contributor recommendations. But the reason is because #2118743 has a single, well-vetted and working patch for something that is only enabled / used during development, and instead of needing to test out various combinations of two separate patches that are still under development. Once the better solution ([#2923634](https://www.drupal.org/i/2923634) and [#2752443](https://www.drupal.org/i/2752443)) get fixed in core, #2118743 should be obviated and no longer required.

Comment: Yay. Its December 2020, and after being postponed for 3+ years, the community has come back around to its senses  :P and has started pushing forward on #2118743 again.

Answer (score 2):

You can see that you get views-view-fields.html.twig for example, the naming conventions is then:

- views-view-fields--foobar--page.html.twig
- views-view-fields--page.html.twig
- views-view-fields--foobar.html.twig
- views-view-fields.html.twig

From: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21views%21views.theme.inc/group/views_templates/8.2.x

In case you have a custom news feed it would look like this:

**views-view-fields--news-feed.html.twig**

where **news-feed** is the machine name of the view.

You can copy the default templates in the stable theme in core to have something to start building from.

Comment: Yes, that I know but I'm used to get more suggestions, see edited question for an extra image of what this looks like.

Comment: Interesting, I see now. Well I did a small test and when I removed my custom template, the suggestions also got removed and when I put the template back I got the suggestions back. Not sure if this is a bug in Drupal but it might explain your problem.

Comment: Hhhmm, strange, I'm working with a custom template. Any suggestions how to fix this?

Comment: Do you get the custom template to show? If not, something with the naming is not corresponding to the template name convention.  If you get it to show I don't know why you don't get name suggestions.

Comment: Yes, the custom theme is working great.