# How do I rewrite the way my view rows are displayed

Tags: views

I created a view and added three fields. A title, a link, and an image.
When adding the image, I set the formatter as URL to image.

How do I rewrite my in my views so that each recipe can have the thumbnail as a background image instead?

In a way, each view row should be structured like this:

```
<article class="recipe" style="background-image: url({{ field_recipe_thumbnail }})">
  <h1>{{ title }}</h1>
  <p>{{ content }}</p>
</article>
```

Is there a way I can do this in my template?
Note: The only question closed to mine that I found is [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/249854/i-dont-see-views-theme-suggestions)

Answer (score 0):

Did you override view ?? If your not override view Please follow below views view suggestion -

views-view-fields--(yourviewmachinename).html.twig 
views-view-unformatted--(yourviewmachinename).html.twig

Note - In views-view-fields--(yourviewmachinename).html.twig,file render your fields which are present in that view Eg. If will have field - title follow below render

{{ fields.title.content }}

Note - If your rendering page title then render {{ label }}

In these file - views-view-unformatted--(yourviewmachinename).html.twig - You will get loop here,don't change here any think.

Hope, this will help you.thanks!