# How to target a specific table with Twig on a specific page?

Tags: theming, 9

I have a table I would like customize in CSS but first need to target it with Twig. The problem I am running into is that the twig template is global so it is for ALL tables. If I edit this table with this twig template, it will change all the tables on all the pages.

> views-view-table.html.twig

In the Twig Documentation, I see no mention of any Table ID's so how do I target this specific table for this page?

[image]

The main table in the center of the page is targeted and edited with this twig template:

> views-view-grouping.html.twig

I want to make the side table look similar but there rendered on 2 different twig templates and I only want to change it for THIS page only and not every table on the rest of the site.

Comment: You need to add template suggestions to get more specific template ids for this view style

Comment: You need a theme suggestion and this answer here helps you: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/227709/adding-theme-suggestions-programmatically-for-views-rows-fields

Comment: See also https://www.drupal.org/docs/theming-drupal/twig-in-drupal/twig-template-naming-conventions#s-views